# Minecraft command block order I need help in redstone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to make a command block that when he found someone(testfor) in a specific condition (like, survival mode) a redstone signal will appear and activate another command block(the command doesn't matter)

If you can please to post a picture of how this setup (in redstone) should look like I will be pleased.

Answer (score 1):

Place a command block with the `/testfor @p[whatever]` command.
Then, a redstone comparator facing **outwards** from the command block.
From there, place your redstone or any redstone contraption that needs the input.

*Note: If the comparator's signal isn't strong enough (1 block worth of power), place a Redstone Repeater after the comparator and any output should now have 15 strength.*

[image: A comparator only outputs a signal power of 1 if the command succeeds. Add a repeater to make that 15.]

Comment: Thanks for the picture @shanodin... I was going to take one right now, but you just saved me the work :)

Comment: Actually @WhynoTalos added the picture, I just edited in the alt-text :)

Comment: You mean 15 strength, not 16, right? Maximum redstone signal strength is 15. (If you *do* mean 16, you can always rollback my edit)